# Django "django-modeladmin-reorder" library does not work for side navigation/nav bar of admin

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, django-modeladmin

I have a django project, which contains several models with natural grouping, as well as some off-the-shelf models from install libraries.

I am trying to have this natural grouping reflected in the admin hope page, as well as the side navigation (nav bar) of the admin panel. By using [django-modeladmin-reorder](https://github.com/mishbahr/django-modeladmin-reorder) library, the home page is properly grouped as I want. Though, the nav bar ordering is not working and the models appear in their original order (alphabetically, grouped by the library/file where they are fetched from).

I have tried several complex (or more complex than just plugging a library) solutions, such as overriding the nav bar/app list html of django and create other templates and creating custom middlewares.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [django-modeladmin-reorder](https://pypi.org/project/django-modeladmin-reorder/) library looks like it is not maintained, with issues (e.g. the [issue](https://github.com/mishbahr/django-modeladmin-reorder/issues/47) already raised in early 2020 for nav-bar customization) in the [github repo](https://github.com/mishbahr/django-modeladmin-reorder) remaining unanswered for 2 to 3 years now. This affects the nav-bar customization, which is supposedly support by the library.

Thankfully, in the same [issue](https://github.com/mishbahr/django-modeladmin-reorder/issues/47), given as an example above, [a user has provided their local repo](https://github.com/mishbahr/django-modeladmin-reorder/issues/47#issuecomment-674782623) for which they are handling the nav-bar functionality. Unfortunately, despite having a PR created, this is not accepted (at the time of writing this).

If you already using the library, moving from the library to the [local repo](https://github.com/bloodwithmilk25/django-modeladmin-reorder) should be easy and nearly plug'n'play. All you have to do is uninstall the library that you already use for the reordering:

```
pip uninstall django-modeladmin-reorder
```

Then you can re-install it through the local report:

```
pip install git+git://github.com/bloodwithmilk25/django-modeladmin-reorder.git@master
```

If that fails you can try to change git+git to git+https:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/bloodwithmilk25/django-modeladmin-reorder.git@master
```

Then all you have to do is to re-run your server and changes should be available both in the homepage and in the nav bar.

> Disclaimer: I have no affiliation to the library or the repo of the user. I was simply trying to find a solution for a couple of days and I found this. I thought to create a question and answer it myself, to let the world know. There is no provision or expectation that the repo will be maintained properly for future version of Django and/or Python. Though, this is the best alternatively that we have now, unless someone wants a completely customize solution (which this repo can serve as a guide either way). Hopefully the user's PR will be accepted and we will be able to move back to the library.

**My custom homepage**

[image: My ordering - Homepage]

**My custom nav bar**

[image: My ordering - Navbar]